# Clear the float in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this code and I'm trying to clear the float using 2 methods:
`overflow` and `clear`, but it don't work as supposed to.

```css
body {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 0 auto;
}

header {
  height: 25%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

header #logo {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
}

header #titre {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  width: 75%;
}

#xd {}

nav {
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

section {
  border-left: 1px solid;
  width: 75%;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}

.clr {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <header>
    <div id="titre">
      <h1>sécurité des réseaux</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="logo">
      <h1>logo</h1>
    </div>
    <br class="clr" />

  </header>
  <div id="xd">
    <nav>
      <h1><a href="#">#</a></h1>
      <h1><a href="#">#</a></h1>
      <h1><a href="#">#</a></h1>
      <h1><a href="#">#</a></h1>
      <h1><a href="#">#</a></h1>

    </nav>
    <section>
      <h1>Firewall (pare-feu)</h1>
      <p>
        Chaque ordinateur connecté à internet (et d'une manière plus générale à n'importe quel réseau informatique) est susceptible d'être victime d'une attaque d'un pirate informatique. La méthodologie généralement employée par le pirate informatique consiste
        à scruter le réseau (en envoyant des paquets de données de manière aléatoire) à la recherche d'une machine connectée, puis à chercher une faille de sécurité afin de l'exploiter et d'accéder aux données s'y trouvant.
      </p>
      <p>Cette menace est d'autant plus grande que la machine est connectée en permanence à internet pour plusieurs raisons :
      </p>
      <ul>
        <li>La machine cible est susceptible d'être connectée sans pour autant être surveillée ;</li>
        <li>La machine cible est généralement connectée avec une plus large bande passante ;
        </li>
        <li>La machine cible ne change pas (ou peu) d'adresse IP.
        </li>

      </ul>

    </section>
    <br class="clr" />

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I don't understand why the text are not at the line with the first element in `nav`.

And also the border it's not complete. Why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is  you have 100% + 1px
there is several method to solve that  one is trick of box module

```
section{box-sizing: border-box;}
```

other is to calculate your size before put it that also work very will

Answer (score 3):

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qvuprc15/)

Add CSS on this tag

```
section{box-sizing: border-box;}
```

Comment: Your width 25% + 75% = 100% + border 1px so not display single line,
So we used 'box-size:border-box' to border includ in 75% section and display single line.

Answer (score 3):

In you code, you are assigning 25% width to nav and 75% width to section. But Section has a 1px border so in the end it's exceeding the 75% assigned. Hence, the whole section is placed under nav.

In your same code, removing the 1px border or making the section width 74% will work as you expect, because there is enough space for that extra pixel.

By the way, I don't think that clearing the float is what you are looking for.

```css
body {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 0 auto;
}

header {
  height: 25%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

header #logo {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
}

header #titre {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  width: 75%;
}

#xd {}

nav {
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

section {
  
  width: 75%;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}

.clr {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <header>
    <div id="titre">
      <h1>sécurité des réseaux</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="logo">
      <h1>logo</h1>
    </div>
    <br class="clr" />

  </header>
  <div id="xd">
    <nav>
      <h1><a href="#">#</a></h1>
      <h1><a href="#">#</a></h1>
      <h1><a href="#">#</a></h1>
      <h1><a href="#">#</a></h1>
      <h1><a href="#">#</a></h1>

    </nav>
    <section>
      <h1>Firewall (pare-feu)</h1>
      <p>
        Chaque ordinateur connecté à internet (et d'une manière plus générale à n'importe quel réseau informatique) est susceptible d'être victime d'une attaque d'un pirate informatique. La méthodologie généralement employée par le pirate informatique consiste
        à scruter le réseau (en envoyant des paquets de données de manière aléatoire) à la recherche d'une machine connectée, puis à chercher une faille de sécurité afin de l'exploiter et d'accéder aux données s'y trouvant.
      </p>
      <p>Cette menace est d'autant plus grande que la machine est connectée en permanence à internet pour plusieurs raisons :
      </p>
      <ul>
        <li>La machine cible est susceptible d'être connectée sans pour autant être surveillée ;</li>
        <li>La machine cible est généralement connectée avec une plus large bande passante ;
        </li>
        <li>La machine cible ne change pas (ou peu) d'adresse IP.
        </li>

      </ul>

    </section>
    <br class="clr" />

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

What Jagdish Parmar propopses is also correct, as it includes the width of the border inside the total width of the box:

```
section{box-sizing: border-box;}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, you have 100% + 1px

```
section {
  border-left: 1px solid;
  width: calc(75% - 1px); // Changed this line
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Live JsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/grinmax_/4qq133mu/